# Optical errors in my published WinForm Project

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I put the debug Folder on another computer to test my little project.

But the colors dont matched and everything looked strange.

See the picture here:

Should look like this one here:

[image]

But acutally looks like this:

[image]

I used the .NetFramework 4
and only simple WinForms.

Thank you.

Edit:
This is no Windows Theme, I have set this colors explicit. 
Here is my DesignerCode: http://www.sourcepod.com/nridub00-5445

Comment: Finding the cause of this issue is going to be difficult just by looking at some screenshots. Could you give us some more information tow work with, e.g.: Have you explicitly set background and foreground colors on all your controls / on your form, or do these derive from the current Windows theme? Could you possibly share some Designer code, e.g. for any one of the controls, so that we see how they are initialized?

Comment: I think I saw something like this before and it was a corrupt system. First try this on another computer with the same OS (I guess XP?) - and make sure that you have the same Framework installed as you use for your project (in .net 4 - there is something like full and client-profile). Try reinstalling the full framework on the troublesome PC if the other works as expcected. If not try on another OS - maybe XP has problems with this (but I don't think so - I have .net 4 WPF projects running on embedded XP as well and no problem)

Answer (score 0):

It sure looks like the user is using a theme (not you).  The theme looks like High Contrast White.

Here is some of your code to set the color.

```
 this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;

 this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
```

You maybe setting the colors but you are setting them to THEIR colors of THEIR theme.  Those constants are for the executing machines color settings, not the developers.   That is why your labels look blank etc.  Try setting one of them to Color.Red instead and I bet it will show up.